# R kable won't print in Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, kable, qwraps2

I have recently tried to use the kable package for tables, and while I'm quite satisfied of the results I'm getting in R scripts, I can't figure out how to use them in an R Markdown file.

Here is a short example of a table that does work in a R script, but won't when I try to reproduce it in a Markdown document.

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars

## @knitr install

check_and_install <- function( packname ) { # given package name, check installation, install if not found
  if ( packname %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE ) {
install.packages( packname, repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/"  )
  }
}

check_and_install("kableExtra")
check_and_install("dplyr")
check_and_install("qwraps2")
check_and_install("reprex")

library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(qwraps2)
library(reprex)

## Tableau

summary_test  <-
  list("Cylindres" =
     list("Huit" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(cyl == 8,show_symbol=TRUE),
          "Six" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(cyl == 6,show_symbol=TRUE),
          "Quatre"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(cyl == 4,show_symbol=TRUE)),
   "Vitesses" =
     list("Cinq" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 5,show_symbol=TRUE),
          "Quatre" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 4,show_symbol=TRUE),
          "Trois" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 3,show_symbol=TRUE))
  )



tabtest2<-summary_table(dplyr::group_by(mtcars, am), summary_test)


kable_out <- kable(tabtest2, format = "html", caption = "",     col.names=c("Auto","Manuelle"), booktabs = T, full_width = F) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  kableExtra::group_rows("Cylindres", 1, 3) %>%
  kableExtra::group_rows("Vitesses", 4, 6) 

kable_out
```

Now as for the next step, I want to include this tab in a R-markdown document, ideally the output would be a word file. And this is where I'm having problems : I can't find a way to include it properly. Markdown completely messes up the formatting in the word output. Please note that there is no issue if I switch the output to HTML... unfortunately I have to provide a word document for now so that's not an option.

````
---
title: "Test2"
author: "MJ"
date: "14 mars 2019"
output: word_document
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = FALSE, include = FALSE)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, cache=FALSE)
read_chunk('C:/Users/Mathieu/Desktop/indicateurs pps/Test SO.R')
```


```{r install, include=FALSE}
```

## Analyse comparative


```{r table1, include=T}
knitr::kable(tabtest2, format = "html", caption = "",     col.names=c("Auto","Manuelle"), booktabs = T, full_width = F) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  kableExtra::group_rows("Cylindres", 1, 3) %>%
  kableExtra::group_rows("Vitesses", 4, 6) 


kable_out
```
````

No issues at all when creating the document, everything seems to run smoothly...

I've been looking into it for a while and I just can't figure out what's wrong. Any leads someone ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding ‘include=T’ in chunk options

Comment: Tried out your code, but it doesn't work because its not reproducible. Could you provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Or better yet create a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/). Otherwise we can't help because your code has objects in there that aren't provided (e.g. what is `praticiens` or `summary_table`?). Thanks!

Comment: @PoGibas : tried that (thought it was enabled by default...), and it somehow... works but in a weird manner : the table appears but all formatting is gone : https://i.imgur.com/jAjPjIH.png

Comment: @Luke : yeah like I said the data involved might be a bit sensitive so I was uneasy uploading it. I removed the touchy parts and uploaded the whole stuff here : http://www.filedropper.com/indicsstack . It contains a simplified R markdown file, an R script with the table, and the csv file needed for calculations. Please let me know if there is something more you need.
Also edited the first post.

Comment: Why are you specifying `format="html"` if you want Word output?

Comment: @Mathieu- It really would help if you made a reprex so we can identify the problem (using fake data of course, it doesn't have to be the real thing). Have you tried what user2554330 above suggested? Don't use `format = "html"` and also try to include `library(knitr)` at the top of the R Markdown document. I've noticed that sometimes that fixes things. Also, your data you uploaded has expired. Or at least the link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hi @Luke, as of now I don't really understand what a reprex is nor how to do it, but I'll look into it and try to provide what you want as soon as possible, tomorrow at worst.
Also, as for what user2554330 it was just me trying to tweak a few things, I changed it back to "word" but to no avail.

Comment: @Luke Ok well I still can't figure out how to make a reprex, so for now I will just try to enclose the code, which I tried to make as simple as I could, using built-in data. First post has been fully edited in that regard.
TL;DR : Markdown actually does print the table now, but the formatting is all over the place.

I hope this will be helpful enough, the only thing you should have to change is the path to the R script and its name if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Before you load the kableExtra package, set:

```
options(kableExtra.auto_format = FALSE)
```

Your table should then show up in the rendered Word document. (Advice taken from [here](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/308))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edits to make the example reproducible @Mathieu -

So a couple of things that I see are going on.

1. You are outputting to Word but want to use html features. Word is not designed for having HTML features (like "hover", "striped", etc).
2. You are trying to create a table from the table creator `kable` from another table creator `summary_table`. If you look at `summary_table`, it actually creates a LaTeX markup table. So there will be problems with converting from one table form to another.

I tested it out and there are three options:

#### Create a word document, but use qwarps2 to create the table

````
---
title: "Test2"
author: "MJ"
date: "14 mars 2019"
output: word_document
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = FALSE, include = FALSE)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, cache=FALSE)
read_chunk("Test SO.R")
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown") # this is new
```


```{r install, include=FALSE}
```

## Analyse comparative

```{r table1, include=TRUE, results='asis'}
tabtest2
```
````

#### Change nothing else and output a HTML document

````
---
title: "Test2"
author: "MJ"
date: "14 mars 2019"
output: html_document
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = FALSE, include = FALSE)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, cache=FALSE)
read_chunk("Test SO.R")
```


```{r install, include=FALSE}
```

## Analyse comparative

```{r table1, include=TRUE, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(tabtest2, caption = "", format = "html", col.names=c("Auto","Manuelle"), booktabs = T,full_width = F) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  kableExtra::group_rows("Cylindres", 1, 3) %>%
  kableExtra::group_rows("Vitesses", 4, 6)
```
````

#### Try a different approach and don't use qwarps2

Why not just create the `knitr` table directly from the data? I.e. don't use qwraps2? To get similar functionality as qwarps2, try the [carpenter](http://carpenter.lukewjohnston.com/) package (disclaimer, I created it, but if it doesn't work there is a list of similar packages at the end of the README/first page). You can get the data into the way you want it for a table then at the end create a table from the wrangled data using knitr.

Comment: Hi Luke, sorry for coming back to you so late, I had to withhold that project for the time being due to other priorities. Thanks a lot for the help, I'll look into it as soon as I can !

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following .Rmd file for an example use case and explanation.

````
---
title: "summary table"
output: rmarkdown::word_document
---

To get the summary table from the
`r  qwraps2::CRANpkg(qwraps2) `
package to render in a word document you need to *not* pass the return from
`r  qwraps2::backtick(summary_test) `
to
`r  paste0(qwraps2::backtick(knitr::kabel), ".") `

The reason is that
`r  qwraps2::backtick(summary_test) `
returns a character matrix and a
`r  qwraps2::backtick(print) `
method is reasponsible for generating either the markdown or LaTeX table.


```{r label = "install_cran", include = FALSE}
# remotes::install_cran is similar to your check_and_install function.
remotes::install_cran("kableExtra")
remotes::install_cran("dplyr")
remotes::install_cran("qwraps2")

```
```{r label = "namespaces"}
library(kableExtra)
library(qwraps2)
```


By default
`r  qwraps2::CRANpkg(qwraps2) `
will format results for LaTeX.  Set the default markup language to markdown
to change this behavior.

```{r }
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
```

**EDIT:** as of version qwraps2 version 0.5.0 the use of the data pronoun
`.data` is no longer needed nor recommented.

```{r label = "define_summary_test"}
summary_test  <-
  list("Cylindres" =
     list("Huit"   = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(cyl == 8, show_symbol = TRUE),
          "Six"    = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(cyl == 6, show_symbol = TRUE),
          "Quatre" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(cyl == 4, show_symbol = TRUE)),
   "Vitesses" =
     list("Cinq"   = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 5, show_symbol = TRUE),
          "Quatre" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 4, show_symbol = TRUE),
          "Trois"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 3, show_symbol = TRUE))
  )
```


Finally, build the table and look at the structure of the object.


```{r label = 'tabtest2'}
tabtest2 <- summary_table(mtcars, summary_test, by = "am")
str(tabtest2)
```


Note that the object is a
`r  qwraps2::backtick(qwraps2_summary_table)  `
is a character matrix with attributes for the row, column, and row group
names.  Using the default print method in R we see a character matrix.

```{r }
print.default(tabtest2)
```


Using the print method for
`r  qwraps2::backtick(qwraps2_summary_table)  `
objects (done impliclity here) gives the markdown:

```{r results = "markup"}
tabtest2
```


To get the table to render nicely use the "asis" value for the results chunk
option:

```{r results = "asis"}
tabtest2
```
````

The output document looks like this:

[image]