# Why is my knitr::kable table not displayed after knitting to word?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I try to knit my rmarkdown file to word and yet, my kable() tables are not shown in the output .docx file?
I used the following code:

```
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```
sub_df%>% kable(col.names = NULL,format="latex", booktabs=TRUE)  %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F)%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down") %>%
  column_spec(1,width = "5in") %>%
      column_spec(2,width = "1in") %>%
      column_spec(3,width = "1in") %>%
      column_spec(4,width = "1in")%>%  
  add_indent(c(2, 3,4))
```

The results were set ({r, results='asis'})

does anyone have an idea why I cannot see the table in my word file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: kableExtra supports HTML and LaTeX output. I don't think it supports Word.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, de tables are not shown in the HTML output either. Do you have an idea why this is?

Comment: Because you specified `format = 'latex'`. LaTeX tables won't work for HTML output (vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

I just answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69130371/11930910). Essentially you need to run

```
options(kableExtra.auto_format = FALSE)
```

before you load the kableExtra library.